# Как удалить ключи по маске используя node_redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

В своем nodejs проекте я использую редис, работа с ним осуществляется с помощью [этой штуки](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)

У меня появилась ситуация, когда необходимо удалить или получить несколько ключей по определенному шаблону. Например есть ключи:

- user:32
- post:965:owner:user:32
- comment:342:post:965:owner:user:32
- comment:389:post:965:owner:user:32
- comment:484:post:965:owner:user:32

Необходимо как-то получить все комменты user'a с id=32, т.е. нужно сделать что-то вроде `redis.get("*comment:*owner:user:32*",cb);`

И например мы удаляем этого юзера и нужно снести из БД всё что с ним связано: `redis.del("*user:32*",cb);`

Как правильно это реализовать используя node_redis? И возможно ли вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключить все эти зависимости для проекта:

```
"redis" : ">=0.12.1",
"redis-scanstreams" : ">=1.0.3",
"stream-to-array" :  ">=2.0.2"
```

Тогда можно так потом получить элементы по шаблону (для Sorted Set):

```
toArray(client.zscan(имя, {pattern: "*comment:*owner:user:32*", count: 20}), function(err, arr) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        // здесь результат в arr
    })
```

Для Hash юзать `hscan`.

Для удаления что-то подобное написать.